# What is the default client-side timeout for WL.Client.invokeProcedure in IBM Worklight?

Tags: timeout, ibm-mobilefirst

When we invoke Worklight's `WL.Client.invokeProcedure`, the second parameter can contain a timeout value. The documentation says:

```
timeout: Integer. Number of milliseconds to wait for the server response before failing with a request timeout.
```

However, it doesn't say what the default timeout is. From observation, it appears that this may be 15s. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If memory serves me right, the default `WL.Client.invokeProcedure` timeout is at 30 seconds.
I don't know how you're testing it, but 15 might just be the amount of time it takes in your setup for it to fail (there could be a failed response from the backend at 15 seconds).

Odd that this is not documented, though. I've opened a documentation defect for this.

Comment: Idan, thanks. I think you *might* be thinking of the server-side `WL.Server.invokeHttp` timeout, which is 30 seconds by default. I don't think the 15-second thing is a failed response from a backend, but we are investigating a complex setup here (hence the question). Anyway, thanks for the thoughts.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier, I've double-checked with the development team, and confirmed that the default timeout in the case of WL.Client.invokeProcedure is 30 seconds as well.